# how to generate control flow graph for a c program by gcc version 3.4.5?

Tags: gcc

I couldn't generate a control flow graph for a c program by `gcc 3.4.5`.
if it is possible help me to generate cfg. I use the following commands but I couldn't find the cfg file.

```
$ gcc -o -dv prog.c -o prog
```

result: unrecognized command line option "-fdump-tree-fixupcfg"

```
$ gcc -fdump-tree-cfg prog.c
```

result: it is not generate any cfg file.
Regards.

Answer (score 5):

GCC 3.4.x is a very ancient version of GCC.

Why don't you use a recent GCC, e.g. GCC **4.6** (or newer) for that purpose? Your `-fdump-tree-cfg` option would then generate a file `prog.c.*`

#### addenda

You may also consider making a GCC plugin, or a [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/) extension (MELT is a domain specific language to extend recent versions of GCC) for that purpose. You'll need a recent version of GCC (4.7 at least).